# How to generate REST API in python using Yang to automate operational commands defined in Yang

Tags: opendaylight

I have netconf server connected to Opendaylight controller and need to automate RPC's defined in yang files to execute against netconf server with ODL controller via RESTCONF POST and parse the response.

RESTCONF API should be able to take all input parameters as per input definitions in yang and test response code and data.

I have tried swagger-codegen but not able to proceed to test with the generated API and parse available input parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The lispflowmapping OpenDaylight project is using [pyangbind](https://github.com/robshakir/pyangbind) for something similar: start from YANG models, [generate python bindings](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=integration/test.git;a=blob;f=csit/suites/lispflowmapping/scripts/generate_bindings.sh;h=be24b62feb9553c3a2f8202f63d236e40dc358ed;hb=HEAD), [import those bindings as libraries](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=integration/test.git;a=blob;f=csit/libraries/JsonGenerator.py;h=4722b614392ba89636114ad2763b663d300e724c;hb=HEAD) and use them to programmatically create the necessary JSON to be used in the REST calls.